# get my image same height as the rest of my edittext controls

Tags: android, css, android-layout-weight

I have an image that is taking up all of the screen. I have tried increasing and decreasing the controls weight, adjust min and max heights and widths but i cant get the image height the same as the other controls.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/header_screenName_textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/appBodyDefault"
    android:textSize="@dimen/titleFontSize"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:text="@string/activity_newuser_header_string" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:background="@color/yellow"
    android:layout_margin="20dp">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/firstName_editText"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="First Name" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/lastName_editText"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="Last Name" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/passwordOne_editText"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="Password" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/passwordTwo_editText"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="Re-type Password" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/email_editText"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="Email" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_profile"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In android scale the image in a good way is hard, I'm using this method for that the image use the full space in the view without lose resolution.
(is only use this in the ImageView)

```
public static void ajustarImageViewToImage(final ImageView iv) {
        ViewTreeObserver observer = iv.getViewTreeObserver();
        observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                //Fazendo o redimensionamento das imagens para de acordo com o VIEW
                Drawable drawable = iv.getDrawable();
                int ih = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
                int iw = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();

                int x = ((iv.getWidth() * ih) / iw) + 1;

                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, x);
                lp.weight = 1;
                lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 10);
                iv.setLayoutParams(lp);
            }
        });
    }
```

if you don't care about the resolution and the scale, try use `android:scaleType="fitXY"` in your ImageView on the XML.